# Converting mysql to Postgre query - could not find proper alternative for information_schema.STATISTICS

Tags: mysql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have a query in mysql, trying to convert to Postgre, I could not find 'information_schema.STATISTICS' equivalent in Postgre. Is there any way to achieve in Postgre.

Full Query:

````
SELECT t.TABLE_NAME as TName
FROM information_schema.TABLES t 
            JOIN information_schema.STATISTICS s on 
              s.TABLE_CATALOG = t.TABLE_CATALOG
            AND s.TABLE_SCHEMA = t.TABLE_SCHEMA
            AND s.TABLE_NAME = t.TABLE_NAME
  AND s.INDEX_NAME  = 'PRIMARY'
             AND s.COLUMN_NAME = 'PK'
  AND s.SEQ_IN_INDEX  = 1
            JOIN information_schema.COLUMNS c on
            c.TABLE_CATALOG = t.TABLE_CATALOG
            AND c.TABLE_SCHEMA = t.TABLE_SCHEMA
              AND c.TABLE_NAME = t.TABLE_NAME 
              AND c.COLUMN_NAME = 'VERSION'
            WHERE 1=1
              AND t.TABLE_NAME LIKE '%\\_%'
              AND t.TABLE_SCHEMA LIKE '%\\_%'
              AND BINARY(t.TABLE_NAME) != LOWER(t.TABLE_NAME)```


In this query, we are trying to get tables which are having PRIMARY as index_name(that is the one index mysql creates automatically), and index_column is PK.
  And also the table should have a column called 'VERSION'.
````

Comment: please don't just show us the query, but explain exactly what it is trying to do; then your question becomes answerable by people who only know postgres but not this particular part of mysql.  and it also helps answerers to know when parts that are mysql specific can be ignored or what they should be replaced with.

Comment: Didn't test, but I think you can get all information from `information_schema.constraint_column_usage`. See also https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/information-schema.html

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a direct equivalent to MySQL's `information_schema.STATISTICS` table in `POSTGRESQL` so have to try with with PostgreSQL's system catalogs `pg_class, pg_attribute, and pg_index` to find tables with a primary key named '`PK`' and a column named '`VERSION`'.

```
SELECT
    t.relname AS "TName"
FROM
    pg_class t
    JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = t.relnamespace
    JOIN pg_attribute a ON a.attrelid = t.oid
    JOIN pg_index i ON i.indrelid = t.oid
    JOIN pg_attribute ia ON ia.attrelid = i.indexrelid
WHERE
    t.relkind = 'r' -- regular table
    AND i.indisprimary = true -- is a primary index
    AND ia.attname = 'pk' -- primary key named 'PK'
    AND a.attname = 'version' -- has a column named 'VERSION'
    AND t.relname LIKE '%\_%' -- table name pattern
    AND n.nspname LIKE '%\_%' -- schema name pattern
    AND t.relname != LOWER(t.relname) -- binary check (case-sensitive)
```